# How can I lock down a Mac to exhibit one website?

Tags: macos, web, locking, mode, kiosk

I'm currently working on a website that will be in an exhibition soon. Users will have a keyboard and mouse in front of them, so I need to lock down the machine to be restricted to just one website. Guided Access mode on iOS is a perfect example. I wish Apple had an OS X version for this reason.

I'm currently trying parental controls but it seems to be quite buggy/not responding to my preferences. I'd really love to just have Chrome or Safari locked to fullscreen somehow so users can't exit the browser/redirect to another website.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you could put Chrome in kiosk mode(can't change website) then change the shortcut keys for exiting out of fullscreen mode if you can on a Mac, and maybe having another desktop and monitor for emergencies. I would have made this a comment but I can't :P This isn't really an answer, just a suggestion. It would really be easier on another OS to do the stuff above.

Answer (score 0):

Recently used 'Web Kiosk' software for exactly this purpose: https://www.macproline.com/webkiosk

It has a lot of options for locking down the machine, both in terms of web sites visited, and disabling key commands, preferences, switching apps, quitting apps, etc.

When searching for a solution for this, I was surprised how few options there were. That said, I would give this a look.